# SQL GroupBy & InnerJoin

Tags: sql, group-by

```
SELECT
   C.SOId, Ser.TotalService, S.TotalSales 
FROM
  salesorder C
  INNER JOIN  (SELECT SOId,SUM(charge) as TotalService FROM sales_serviceline GROUP BY SOId)  Ser
  ON C.SOId = Ser.SOId
  INNER JOIN  (SELECT SOId,SUM(PriceEach*qty) as TotalSales FROM  salesline  GROUP BY  SOId)  S
  ON C.SOId = S.SOId
```

Explanation : 
One SalesOrder has many salesline's
One SalesOrder has many salesline services's

so if a salesorder has saleslins & salesline_service then the above query successfully retrives the total amount of that salesorder but if there's only salineline or only salesline service that sales order is not retried how to change this query to get all the results ?

Comment: What is the problem ? What you mean by "all the results" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `LEFT JOIN`. If there is no rows in `Ser` or `S` then the `LEFT JOIN` will make `TotalService` or `TotalSales` `NULL`

```
SELECT
   C.SOId, Ser.TotalService, S.TotalSales 
FROM
  salesorder C
  LEFT JOIN  (SELECT SOId,SUM(charge) as TotalService FROM sales_serviceline GROUP BY SOId)  Ser
  ON C.SOId = Ser.SOId
  LEFT JOIN  (SELECT SOId,SUM(PriceEach*qty) as TotalSales FROM  salesline  GROUP BY  SOId)  S
  ON C.SOId = S.SOId
```

If you do not want to have them as NULL. Then you can quit easy use `COALESCE()`. Like this:

```
SELECT
   C.SOId, 
   COALESCE(Ser.TotalService,0) AS TotalService, 
   COALESCE(S.TotalSales,0) AS TotalSales
FROM
  salesorder C
  LEFT JOIN  (SELECT SOId,SUM(charge) as TotalService FROM sales_serviceline GROUP BY SOId)  Ser
  ON C.SOId = Ser.SOId
  LEFT JOIN  (SELECT SOId,SUM(PriceEach*qty) as TotalSales FROM  salesline  GROUP BY  SOId)  S
  ON C.SOId = S.SOId
```

Comment: `ISNULL()` is a MySQL function. The ANSI standard defines `COALESCE()` which can be used in almost all DBMS.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. SQL-Server has `ISNULL()`. MySQL has the equivalent `IFNULL()`. (MySQL's `ISNULL()` does something different)